# How to make have a if statement run after a nested for loop is complete?

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is a way to run a if loop after a loop is complete without removing it from the loop
this is the program I have to do for my com sci class

Write a program that finds the integer from 1 to 1000 with the most factors. For example, 60 has
12 factors: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, and 60. Keep track of the number of factors for each
integer from 1 to 1000 in the nested for. When the nested for is done, you program should know
which integer has the most factors. Use a separate for loop to output each of the factors.
this is the code I have

```
public class program45{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int count=0,count1=0,num1=0;
        for (int num=1; num<=1000; num++ ){
            for(int facnum=1; facnum<=num; facnum++){
                if(num%facnum==0){
                    count++;
                }
                if(count>count1){
                    num1=num;
                    count1=count;
                    count=0;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(num1+" has the most factors");
        System.out.print("they are ");
        for(int facnum1=1; facnum1<=num1; facnum1++){
            if (num1%facnum1==0){
                System.out.print(facnum1+", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

already tried putting second if statement in a nested if.

Comment: Move the second `if` statement out of the inner `for`, but keep it inside the outer `for`.  Also, move variable `count` into the outer loop.  *Do not* reset it inside the `if` statement.

Comment: I've formatted your code for  you, but you will want to do this yourself in the future. Please understand that this is important and that proper code formatting is not something whose purpose is just to make code look "pretty" but rather when done correctly to make code much easier to read, understand and debug, both for us and more importantly for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class program45{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int count1=0,num1=0;
        for (int num=1; num<=1000; num++ ){
            int count=0
            for(int facnum=1; facnum<=num; facnum++){
                if(num%facnum==0){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count>count1){
                num1=num;
                count1=count;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(num1+" has the most factors");
        System.out.print("they are ");
        for(int facnum1=1; facnum1<=num1; facnum1++){
            if (num1%facnum1==0){
                System.out.print(facnum1+", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, if only to help future visitors with similar problems